# THREE.js, I don't know why not rendering obj files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm making obj loader in react view button clicked, I want to see obj file in modal component.This object loader component get url to modal component.

console.log is correct.This loader is get url other component.

> Group {uuid: "0C86CC1D-E795-4191-A62A-72DF4A433CEB", name: "", type:
>   "Group", parent: null, children: Array(8), …} castShadow:
>   falsechildren: (8) [Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh,
>   Mesh]frustumCulled: truelayers: Layers {mask: 1}materialLibraries:
>   ["patient.mtl"]matrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}matrixAutoUpdate:
>   truematrixWorld: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}matrixWorldNeedsUpdate:
>   falsename: ""parent: Scene {uuid:
>   "873E8718-F1B0-47B5-AC77-DC1B334B3637", name: "", type: "Scene",
>   parent: null, children: Array(5), …}position: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z:
>   0}quaternion: Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1,
>   _onChangeCallback: ƒ}receiveShadow: falserenderOrder: 0rotation: Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", _onChangeCallback: ƒ}scale:
>   Vector3 {x: 0.07, y: 0.07, z: 0.07}type: "Group"up: Vector3 {x: 0, y:
>   1, z: 0}userData: {}uuid:
>   "0C86CC1D-E795-4191-A62A-72DF4A433CEB"visible: trueeulerOrder:
>   (...)id: 18modelViewMatrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}normalMatrix:
>   Matrix3 {elements: Array(9)} useQuaternion: (...)**proto**: Object3D
>   (8) [Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh, Mesh]
>
> Scene {uuid: "873E8718-F1B0-47B5-AC77-DC1B334B3637", name: "", type:
>   "Scene", parent: null, children: Array(5), …}

**CODE**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import OBJLoader from "three-obj-loader";
import OrbitControls from "three-orbitcontrols";
OBJLoader(THREE);

let scene;

class ObjectLoader extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth;
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 1, 2000);
    this.camera.position.z = 250;

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setClearColor("#263238");
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "#0F0",
      wireframe: true
    });
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(this.cube);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);


    //LIGHTS
    var lights = [];
    lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0x304ffe, 1, 0);
    lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
    lights[0].position.set(0, 200, 0);
    lights[1].position.set(100, 200, 100);
    lights[2].position.set(-100, -200, -100);
    scene.add(lights[0]);
    scene.add(lights[1]);
    scene.add(lights[2]);

    // load Object
    loadObj(this.props.url);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop();
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  }

  start = () => {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  };

  stop = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  };

  animate = () => {
    this.renderScene();
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  };

  renderScene = () => {
    if (this.renderer) this.renderer.render(scene, this.camera);
  };

  onLoad = () => {
    this.renderScene();
    //start animation
    this.start();
  };

  onProgress = xhr => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
  };

  // Function called when download errors
  onError = error => {
    console.log("An error happened" + error);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}
        ref={mount => {
          this.mount = mount;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

function loadObj(url) {
  const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.load(
    url,
    function(object) {
      console.log(object, object.children);
      let mesh = object;
      scene.add(object);
      console.log(scene);
      mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      mesh.scale.set(0.07, 0.07, 0.07);
    },
    function(xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function(error) {
      console.log("An error happened" + error);
    });
}


export default ObjectLoader;
```

Comment: Can you please share your code as a live example? Or maybe as a github repo? It will be more easy to provide feedback if it's possible to debug the issue.

Comment: @Mugen87 
Thanks to your answer. and I resolved my problem thanks!